# disable tab-scrolling in Chrome/Chromium

Tags: linux, google-chrome, chromium, tabs

Is there a chrome/chromium build that addresses the anti-feature discussed [here](https://superuser.com/questions/709078/chrome-how-to-disable-scroll-over-tabs), where making the mistake of scrolling while the cursor is over the tab bar has the effect of scrolling to random tabs? Specifically I'm interested in a build that reverts this [behavior](https://codereview.chromium.org/155053).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works on ubuntu 20, chromium 93:

- go to `chrome://flags/#scrollable`
- to enable scrolling, set to defaults: "Tab Scrolling" and "Tab Scrolling Buttons"
- to disable scrolling, enable: "Tab Scrolling" and "Tab Scrolling Buttons"
- Restart chrome/chromium

**Update 2022.02.25**

It seems like they've renamed things (in chromium at least). Here are the new steps:

- Navigate to chrome://flags/
- In the search bar, search for "Scroll switches tab"
- In the dropdown select, "Never"
- Restart chromium

Comment: It feels like an eternity since I posted this question. Thank you so much!

Comment: As a bonus, since I've since switched to firefox. Here's the relevant setting in about:config for firefox: "toolkit.tabbox.switchByScrolling". Setting this to "false" will disable the same annoying behavior in firefox :)

Comment: I just used that in my firefox, thanks! Nice trade :)

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to place your vote by starring an issue to fix this bug at https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=680499. It wouldn't hurt if you found several more (or several hundred more) people to do the same. Once enough people star the issue, developers will get to work and get the option added so you can easily disable (or enable if you like) this functionality.